# Regular expression to extract "Boolean" and "MessageString" from {'result':(Boolean, MessageString)}

Tags: python, regex

How to parse the string `" {'result':(Boolean, MessageString)} "` using Python regular expressions to get `Boolean` and the `MessageString` separated into variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> x = re.search('\((.*),\s*(.*)\)', " {'result':(Boolean, MessageString)} ")
>>> x.group(1)
'Boolean'
>>> x.group(2)
'MessageString'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a dictionary+tuple in Python syntax, so eval() would also work (if you trust the source!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need there can be other solution than regular expression. For this particular example the following code will work:

```
>>> compile("{'result':(Boolean, MessageString)}", '<expr>', 'eval').co_names
('Boolean', 'MessageString')
```

There is also [`parser`](http://docs.python.org/library/parser.html#module-parser) module which might be useful for such tasks.